# Is 7 the only solution for $n!+1 \equiv 0 \mod 10n+1, n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+} $?

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, factorial

I've tested each $0<n<10^5$, it seems that 7 is the only solution for $n!+1 \equiv 0 \mod 10n+1$. But I can't prove it correct or wrong.

I know that no solution exists if $10n+1$ is composite, because any factor p (p>1) of $10n+1$ must be greater than n, so $10n+1 \ge (n+1)^2$, that's $n \le 8$. I've checked them one by one, no solution found.

But when $10n+1$ is a prime, I can't work it out. Anyone can help?

**Updated at Nov 26, 2021**

Still no answer yet, just put some of my studies here.

When $n \gt 5$,

$n!+1 \equiv 0 (\mod 10n+1)$

$n!+1 \equiv 1 (\mod 10n)$

since $10n+1$ and $10n$ are coprime, [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) gives
$n!+1=(10n+1)^2 + 10n(10n+1)k$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0} $.

If $k=0$, $n!+1=(10n+1)^2$, $n=7$ is the only solution.

If $k \gt 0$, no progress at all :(

Comment: Why must any factor of $10n+1$ be greater than $n$?

Comment: @runway44  when 10n + 1 has a factor $1 \lt p \le n$, n is not a solution for sure.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire  $n!+1$ is divisible by $10n+1$ and all its factors. If $p$ ($1 \lt p \le n$) is a factor of $10n+1$,  $n!+1$ is divisible by $p$, which contradicts the fact of $n! + 1 \equiv 1 (\mod p)$.

Comment: @DaiShuo Thanks, I missed that simple observation.

Comment: If we assume that for a prime $p=10n+1$ , the chance that it divides $n!+1$ is $\frac{1}{p}$ , then we can expect infinite many solutions, although the second solution can be so large that it can barely be detected. This is because the sum of the reciprocals of the primes of the form $10n+1$ is known to be divergent.

Comment: Upto $n=10^6$ , there is no further solution.

Comment: If we replace $10$ with $6$ then the first solution is $p = 6n + 1 = 4729$.